# How do I extract an ISO file?

Tags: nautilus, iso, extract

I've seen tutorials online, but whenever I try the same thing as there it says that the file is not found? Does it have to be in a specific place or???

I've tried using p7zip (on terminal it shows Unknown error -2147024872, but when I try to extract normally without terminal it shows Ignoring out-of-order file @19 (README.TXT) 51200 < 55296) and when I open it with archive manager it only shows a single folder labeled with a single period (".") and with nothing in it, says it's 0 bytes but the iso is 3.3GB

It's a Windows 7 installation ISO, i'm trying to extract it to a new partition, and I've also tried extracting it to my normal Ubuntu drive but it shows the same error

I have also tried extracting without p7zip in terminal and it says that the file isn't found

I have also tried a different ISO file but it shows the same thing

EDIT: I mounted the ISO file and opened it in Nautilus only to see a readme.txt file. It said: "This disc contains a "UDF" file system and requires an operating system that supports the ISO-13346 "UDF" file system specification."
Help

Comment: chances are higher that iso file is corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mounted the ISO file and opened it in Nautilus only to see a readme.txt file. It said: "This disc contains a "UDF" file system and requires an operating system that supports the ISO-13346 "UDF" file system specification." Help

You are almost there. You need to mount it and tell it it is ISO-13346. Something like this:

```
sudo mount -t udf file.iso /media/iso
```

or

```
sudo mount -t udf, iso13346 -o loop file.iso /media/iso
```

(There is a ton of other options but this should be the base; change file.iso for your iso and change /media/iso to something else if you want).

Comment: mount: /media/io: special device WIN7.iso does not exist. Do I have to put it somewhere?

Comment: you need to point to the iso file. If it is in anothe dir than WIN7.iso you need to add the dir.

Comment: tysm it worked!